# how to get an uniq id or order id to identify each user pay action in app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now I am develop an IAP using flutter, I could not identify the user pay now. Each time when enter into pay page, the app generate a new receipt. The I am using the `transaction_id` field in the `latest_receipt_info` field from receipt verify response. But  now I found the `transaction_id` are always changed(not one pay action one transaction id). Then my server side generate more than 2000+ pay record from reading  `latest_receipt_info` from response(I am absolute sure the pay action less than 20, 2000+ is absolutely wrong, I am very sure). I have already added uniq constraint with transaction id. And I am sure I did not pay for 2000+ times(only one user to test IAP pay of iOS).

- how to identify the user pay action or get the order id(if I could not identify user pay action, maybe a little user pay but generate many records in the server side)?
- if transaction id could not use, which field should I use?

By the way, this is my table design:

```
CREATE TABLE public.pay_transaction_record (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    transaction_id varchar NOT NULL,
    in_app_ownership_type varchar NOT NULL,
    quantity int4 NOT NULL,
    origianl_transaction_id varchar NOT NULL,
    subscription_group_identifier varchar NOT NULL,
    purchase_date_pst varchar NOT NULL,
    original_purchase_date varchar NULL,
    original_purchase_date_ms int8 NULL,
    original_purchase_date_pst varchar NULL,
    original_application_version varchar NULL,
    is_in_intro_offer_period int4 NULL,
    expires_date varchar NULL,
    is_trial_period int4 NOT NULL,
    expire_date_pst varchar NOT NULL,
    expire_date_ms int8 NULL,
    product_id varchar NULL,
    purchase_date varchar NULL,
    web_order_line_item_id varchar NULL,
    user_id int8 NULL,
    app_id int4 NULL,
    purchase_date_ms int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unique_transaction_id UNIQUE (transaction_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a checkout session? Or a checkout session ID? might help you collect all transaction that are made in a single checkout session.

Comment: apple in app purchase have a checkout session? what is checkout session?@SaleemKhair